# How to use Put method in web api

Tags: c#, android, put, webapi

here my put method

```
         
        [Route("api/SPSOnHand/itemcode/{item_code}")]
        [HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage Put(String itemcode, [FromBody]SPS_ONHAND _member)
        {
           
            var memberdetail = (from a in db.SPS_ONHANDs where a.ITEM_CODE == itemcode select a).FirstOrDefault();
  
            if (memberdetail != null)
            {
      
                memberdetail.ONHAND_QTY = _member.ONHAND_QTY;
                memberdetail.OPR_ID = _member.OPR_ID;
                memberdetail.DATE = _member.DATE;
 
                db.SubmitChanges();

                  
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, memberdetail);
            }
            else
            {
                  
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Invalid Code or Member Not Found");
            }


        }
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

here what i test in fiddler
[image]

what should i do.. i want to update my table using itemcode instead of id

Comment: there are too many things that may be wrong (like `itemcode` value missing from the query string). I'd like to suggest you to create simple `api/SPSOnHand/itemcode` method with the `[FromBody]SPS_ONHAND` parameter in the body only and check how it goes. Than you may adjust  it slowly and add `itemcode` parameter (and check again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the binding parameter has to be the same name as the placeholder in the route-definition. Try this:

```
    [Route("api/SPSOnHand/itemcode/{item_code}")]
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(string item_code, [FromBody]SPS_ONHAND _member)
    {  
         var memberdetail = (from a in db.SPS_ONHANDs where a.ITEM_CODE == item_code select a).FirstOrDefault();
         ....
    }
```